# Debug assertion failed when launching from exe file (visual studio)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl

I got stumped, tried everything from optimization setting to setting to a different runtime library.

I'm getting this error only when i run my project from the `.exe`.
Maybe somebody had the same issue and knows how to fix.

MDd mode output:

```
Debug Assertion Failed!
Program \x64\Debug\FRTI.exe
File:minkernel\crts\ucrt\src\appcrt\stdio\fseek.cpp
Line: 180

Expression: stream.valid
```

And the possible suspect of this error.

```
memset(data, 0, length + 1);
fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);
fread(data, 1, length, file);
fclose(file);
```

Judging by the error.

Comment: Maybe the file is not read (because its in the wrong folder) and you have no error handling so you try to seek anyways. Remember if you run/ debug your application in VS the default folder is the one containing the project file. If you click on the executable in the file explorer of windows the default folder moves to the location of the executable.

Comment: What is `data`?  What is `file`?  Have you properly constructed `file` and used it to successfully open a file?  [Edit] your question to add the code showing these details.  As it is it is not a [mcve].

Comment: stream.valid assert failed . Think yourself

Comment: Thank you @drescherjm I found out that i have to relocate my exe file to folder which contains project files to work.

Answer (score 0):

The error was mainly because my shader file read program haven't detected Shader folder.
Its been fixed by just relocating .exe file to project folder.

Big thanks to @drescherjm.

Comment: I think you should fix your code to handle the different path also add some error handling to make your code robust.

Comment: Well i'm gonna consider it later,It's just that i needed to show my prototype off for progress check.